# Homomorphisms of free modules that have a GL-action

Tags: commutative-algebra, representation-theory

Let $S$ be a commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra that is a representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (for example the polynomial ring $S=\text{Sym}(\mathbb{C}^n)$). Let $\lambda$ be a dominant integral weight and let $S_{\lambda}\mathbb{C}^n$ denote the simple representation of highest weight $\lambda$.

The $S$-module $\text{Hom}_S(S\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}S_{\lambda}\mathbb{C}^n, S)$ is a representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is it easy to see how this decomposes as a $GL$-module? What about in the case when $S$ is a polynomial ring as above?

My guess is that it is isomorphic to $S\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}S_{\lambda}\mathbb{C}^n$ or its vector space dual.